# Spring data CURD Repository failing for multiple objects on save call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have defined the entity class ExportRecordStatus having Integer Id like one of the attributes.

ExportRecordStatus is defined with all the values and on save it get saved for a single entity but fails for multiple entities.

exportRecordStatusList has following entries :

```
[ExportRecordStatus 
[Id=null, runId=55801, mdmItemId=1111, endPointItemId=null, statusTime=xxxxx, endPointName=xxx, status=ERROR, detailStatus=xxxx, endPointResponseCode=null],

ExportRecordStatus
[Id=null, runId=55801, mdmItemId=2222, endPointItemId=null, statusTime=xxxx, endPointName=xxx, status=ERROR, detailStatus=xxx, endPointResponseCode=null]
]
Id being primary key.
```

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not
>   execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement

the entity is define as with Id attribute is annoted with following :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "qconn_ers_id")
@SequenceGenerator(name="qconn_ers_id", sequenceName = "qconn_ers_id", allocationSize=1)
@Column(name = "ERS_ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
pdefined Integer Id;
```

I have define the repository class as following

```
public interface ExportRecordStatusCRUDRepository extends CrudRepository<ExportRecordStatus, Integer> {}
```

On calling for single object, It works for a single object.

> exportRecordStatusCRUDRepository.save(exportRecordStatus);

**but in case of multiple objects it fails and throws an exception.**

The save should be successful with Id should have unique value for each ExportRecordStatus object.

Full Stack is copied below-

```
2019-02-19 14:23:56,244 ERROR c.i.m.c.a.p.AllExceptionsProcessor [Camel (camel-1) thread #6 - Threads] STOPPING the processing of becuase of exception  could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statementStackTrace  org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:278)at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521) at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761) at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118.save(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.mdm.camel.adobe.processor.WriteResponseToDBProcessor.process(WriteResponseToDBProcessor.java:72) at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63) at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:76)at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:76)at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)  at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.access$100(Pipeline.java:43)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline$1.done(Pipeline.java:157)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.ThreadsProcessor$ProcessCall.run(ThreadsProcessor.java:87)at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:522)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
```

Need help on this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: show us full stacktrace

Comment: When saving a single object, the Id has the expected value regarding the generator?

Comment: try to to leave `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)` and remove `SequenceGenerator` annotation

Comment: your column name is "ERS_ID" and a query is shown "Id" maybe after added hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop will solve your problem

Comment: @Maciej Kowalski : Added the full stacktrace that might help, @ Sergio Lema: I can only see that the Id value is null and it get define automatically on save call, yes when there is single entity it works fine.

Comment: have you set the property hibernate.jdbc.batch_size to a non zero value?

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this, there was issue the way I was binding the entity class attributes and database, there were 2 attributes which were defined with unique constraint and somehow my application was pushing same timestamp for 2 records and it was failing.
Thank you folks for all the quick inputs.